# WordPress sort post query by date field, but formatted as a string (April 12, 2012)

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm trying to sort a post query, I'm using Advanced custom fields to populate each post with a field called date. The value of the field is a date formatted as a string, example (April 12, 2012).

Due to it being formatted as a string I can't sort it using Wordpress's orderby Date query, but I need them to be ordered by their date value.

I've tried looping through the query, storing the post objects into an array, converting the string dates into numerical dates and then sorting the resulting numerical date array. Which works, but I just end up with a sorted array of numerical dates, If I can get a way to query that sorted array of dates in the order that the array has them in, I can get this solved.

Comment: From this post: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-compare-between-two-dates-in-a-wordpress-loop/ we realised that ACF date is stored as Ymd (20180702). Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: This isn't using ACF's date picker, it's using a text box. So the data is likely stored as a string "April 12, 2012" I need to do it this way, as it's synced with a separate API and I can only sync strings